# How to measure the performance of OFDM System using Error Vector Magnitude

Tags: ofdm, performance

I have used BER vs. Tx-Gain in dB curve as one tool to measure my ofdm system's performance. Besides, I would like to measure the performance using the EVM.

How I can implement this EVM measurement in the same way as BER curve using matlab!

I am using several baseband modulation schemes like BPSK, QAM, 16QAM and 64QAM in my OFDM-System.

I would appreciate your support and guidance.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.evm-system-object.html